# Menu :first-child and :hover

Tags: css, menu

I have horizontal menu, on both sides with `border-radius`. When each element is active it has `background-color`. I set background on first element by using `:first-child`, but I have problem with `:hover`. I need on first element hover with radius on top-left and bottom-left. At this moment `:hover` is basic rectangle.

Here's the code

```
ul.nav li.current-menu-item:first-child a, ul.nav li.current_page_item:first-child a {
color: #ffffff;
background: url(../gfx/menu_hover.gif) left top repeat-x;
border-top-left-radius:7px;
border-bottom-left-radius:7px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow :hover for the menu to get the effect as shown below.

```
ul.nav li.current-menu-item:first-child a:hover, 
ul.nav li.current_page_item:first-child a:hover
```

Comment: I've tried it this way before, but it does not work.

Comment: Can you share the code in a fiddle to check the issue?

Comment: Ok, I deleted current_page_item and it works but I have problem with corners. I set hover to red to show how it looks like. On hover there are some dark corners. How to get rid of them? See on screen https://s17.postimg.org/kp29ckn27/hover.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, as you are saying, but one more problem may be that `a` tag may be inherited from it's parent:

So you need to use `!important` in `border-radius` rule...

```
ul.nav li.current-menu-item:first-child a,
ul.nav li.current_page_item:first-child a {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: url(../gfx/menu_hover.gif) left top repeat-x;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px !important;     /* added !important here */
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px !important;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I deleted current_page_item and it works but I have problem with corners. I set hover to red to show how it looks like. On hover there are some dark corners. How to get rid of them? See on screen https://s17.postimg.org/kp29ckn27/hover.jpg

Comment: Set `border-radius: 7px;` and `overflow: hidden;`  in `ul.nav` also.